# getArgument().getInt() returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I just started programming and I don't know much, so I apologize if what I'm asking is obvious.

I'm making an icon pack dashboard app and I'm copy & pasting code from open source templates into my projects. I know it isn't the best thing to do, but I'm just trying to understand how complex things work.

I've read some similar issues, but I'd need a step-by-step guide.

Now, I'm facing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.squaredlab.oblivion.app.Fragment.IconsFragment$IconAdapter.loadIcon(IconsFragment.java:117)
    at com.squaredlab.oblivion.app.Fragment.IconsFragment$IconAdapter.<init>(IconsFragment.java:50)
    at com.squaredlab.oblivion.app.Fragment.IconsFragment.onCreateView(IconsFragment.java:30)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I don't know what the problem is. The open source project I'm looking at works like a charm, obviously.

This is the code:

```
public class IconsFragment extends Fragment {

private String[] iconsnames;
public IconAdapter icAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    icAdapter = new IconAdapter();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icons_grid, container, false);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.icons_grid);
    gridview.setColumnWidth(convertToPixel(72) + convertToPixel(4));
    gridview.setAdapter(icAdapter);
    return view;
}

public static IconsFragment newInstance(int iconsArray) {
    IconsFragment fragment = new IconsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("iconsArrayId", iconsArray);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

private class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;

    public IconAdapter() {
        loadIcon();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        IconsHolder holder;
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_icon, parent, false);
            holder = new IconsHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (IconsHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.icon.startAnimation(anim);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
        holder.content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View dialogIconView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_icon, null);
                ImageView dialogIcon = (ImageView) dialogIconView.findViewById(R.id.dialogicon);
                dialogIcon.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
                String name = iconsnames[position].toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .customView(dialogIconView, false)
                        .title(convertText(name))
                        .positiveText(R.string.close)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    class IconsHolder {

        final ImageView icon;
        final MaterialRippleLayout content;

        IconsHolder(View v) {
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_img);
            content = (MaterialRippleLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.icons_ripple);
        }
    }

    private void loadIcon() {
        mThumbs = new ArrayList<>();
        final Resources resources = getResources();
        final String packageName = getActivity().getApplication().getPackageName();
        addIcon(resources, packageName, getArguments().getInt("iconsArrayId", 0));
    }

    private void addIcon(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
        iconsnames = resources.getStringArray(list);
        for (String extra : iconsnames) {
            int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
            if (res != 0) {
                final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
                if (thumbRes != 0)
                    mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
            }
        }
    }

}

private int convertToPixel(int dp) {
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
            getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return (int) px;
}

private String convertText(String name) {
    String partialConvertedText = name.replaceAll("_", " ");
    String[] text = partialConvertedText.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (text[0].length() > 0) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(text[0].charAt(0))).append(text[0].subSequence(1, text[0].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
        for (int i = 1; i < text.length; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(text[i].charAt(0))).append(text[i].subSequence(1, text[i].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

This is where I instantiate the Fragment (3rd case of the switch)

```
public class SimpleHeaderDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//save our header or result
private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
private Drawer result = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_fragment_dark_toolbar);

    // Handle Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Create the AccountHeader
    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();

    //Create the drawer
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_launchers).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_star),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_wallpapers).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_image),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_takealook).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_search),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_iconlist).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sort_alpha_asc),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_requesticons).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_edit),
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_section_header),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_help).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question).setEnabled(false),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_contact).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bullhorn)
    ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(((Nameable) drawerItem).getNameRes());
                        //ignore the DemoFragment and it's layout it's just to showcase the handle with an keyboard
                        Fragment f = DemoFragment.newInstance(getResources().getString(((Nameable) drawerItem).getNameRes()));

                        switch (position) {
                            //case 0:
                            //    f = new IconListFragment();
                            //    break;
                            //case 1:
                            //    f = new IconListFragment();
                            //    break;
                            case 2:
                                f = new WallpapersFragment();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                f = new IconsFragment();
                                break;
                            //case 4:
                            //    f = new IconListFragment();
                            //    break;
                            //case 5:
                            //    f = new IconListFragment();
                            //    break;
                            //case 6;
                            //startActivity(new Intent(this, RequestActivity.class));
                            //break;
                        }

                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withOnDrawerListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                }
            })
            .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();

    //react on the keyboard
    result.keyboardSupportEnabled(this, true);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
    outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
    if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
        result.closeDrawer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not Javascript related... also it appears your `getArguments()` method call returned null.

Comment: Do you create your Fragment using the static _newInstance_ method?

Comment: @harism Yes, I did:
public static IconsFragment newInstance(int iconsArray) {
        .....
    }

Comment: What if you do `getActivity().getArguments()`?

Comment: `Cannot resolve method getArguments()` @EricMartinez

Comment: Where is your code that tries to get the "iconsArrayId" key from the bundle?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe there isn't... Could you guide me? @Eenvincible

Comment: I mean where are you trying to get that value that you stored in the bundle? You see, normally after you set the arguments to a fragment, you probably want to get that value somewhere. To do so, you simply do (this).getArguments(). So, where is your code that does that?

Comment: There isn't that code, I didn't do it. If I try to replace my broken line with what you said I get a `Cannot resolve method getArguments()` error. Is it normal? @Eenvincible

Comment: Show the code where you call `newInstance()`. We see you defined it, but you're not showing where/how you're using it. My guess is, you aren't, and   you're instantiating the `Fragment` via it's constructor instead.

Comment: You are right! What do I have to do? @ci_

Comment: Well, instantiate your Fragment using newInstance, like `IconsFragment  fragment = IconsFragment.newInstance(iconsArray)`

Comment: But where do I have to instantiate it? I'm really lost at the moment @ci_

Comment: Where do you instantiate it now? Maybe show some more code.

Comment: How can I contact you? Email? @ci_

Comment: You can edit your question. Just show us where and how you're currently instantiating your Fragment. Somewhere will be a `new IconsFragment()` most likely, show us that and some context.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question adding the code where I instantate that Fragment. @ci_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling IconsFragment.newInstance() at all!

Instead of

```
  case 3:
         f = new IconsFragment();
         break;
```

Do this

```
  case 3:
        f = IconsFragment.newInstance(*provide int value here*);
        break;
```

Comment: I would give you a medal if I could. Thank you so much!
(what value should I provide? I'm confused)

Comment: It know gives me this error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x1
            at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:549)
            at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.app.Fragment.IconsFragment$IconAdapter.addIcon(IconsFragment.java:122)`

Comment: That value is iconsArrayId that you have to put into arguments in newInstance().  BTW, What is iconsArrayId? ISs that a drawble? something like "R.drawable.ic_project_icon" ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you do not setArguments in IconsFragment.newInstance method. Do you call it? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()

Comment: I did set it, I think. I'm a very newbie! Isn't it correct what you see in my IconsFragment.newInstance method?